# Control YUI DataTable Record IDs

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a `DataTable` in YUI and I want to have the record ID be from my data instead of `yui-rec1` ...

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is a private property** called _sId which store record id. It follows this pattern

```
this._sId = "yui-rec" + this._nCount;
```

Sorry but recordSet API does not allow you to modify record id.

Comment: @Kristopher Ives Thank you. If you want, see here: http://jsbin.com/ideha a nice application whose datatable instances allows you to select a single and multiple rows at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

`dataTAble.getRecord` method

```
YAHOO.widget.Record getRecord ( row )

For the given identifier, returns the associated Record instance.
Parameters:
row <HTMLElement | Number | String> DOM reference to a TR element (or child of a TR element), RecordSet position index, or Record ID.
Returns: YAHOO.widget.Record
Record instance.
```

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html

Or you need something else?